# Specify the string display java

Tags: java

I would like to know how to display a string (character by character) with Java, that is to say, a display char in a JTextField and then display another after 2 seconds for example?

Can someone point me how to fix this?

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   String s = jTextField4.getText (), s1 = "";
   String str = "";
   int L = s.length();
   int x = 1500;
   for (int i=0; i< L; i++) 
   {
        char prem = s.charAt(i);
        str= str + prem;
        x = x + 2000;
        final Thread th4 = new Thread (new  Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(x);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {                 
                }
            }
        });
        th4.start();
        s1 = s1.concat(str);
        jTextField3.setText(s1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? i.e. what does it do? what do you want it to do?

Comment: What is a "display tank"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   Thread thread = new Thread(new DelayedWriter(jTextField3, jTextField4.getText()));
   thread.start();
}

class DelayedWriter implements Runnable{
    JTextField tf;
    String s;
    public DelayedWriter(JTextField tf, String s){
        this.tf = tf;
        this.s=s;
    }
    public void run(){
        for (int i=0; i< s.length(); i++) 
        {
            tf.setText(s.substring(0,i+1));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://im80.gulfup.com/xlFrFW.png
:/
thank u a looooooot . 
just this . What is the solution.

Comment: @Azo add `import javax.swing.JTextField;` somewhere at the begining. `sopy` is class name I used, just remove this line